# Convert SQLite 3 database to CSV

Tags: database, sqlite

I am looking for a way to convert my databases into CSV files. I use SQLite 3 through the terminal as well as from SQLiteStudio.  I have not come across a simple way to export or save as a CSV, which makes me think I may not be able to do it in one step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `sqlite3` command-line shell, this is possible for single tables:

```
sqlite> create table t(x,y);
sqlite> insert into t values(1, 'hello'), (2, 'world');
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> select * from t;
1,hello
2,world
```

You can use `.output` or `.once` to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: This adds Windows newlines `\n\r` (or `^M` in emacs) instead of just Unix newlines `\n`.

Comment: @Boris This is required by RFC 4180.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in linux you need binary file [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) dan single bash file.
My sample code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH_BIN="/home/user/project/bin/";

PATH_SOURCE=$PATH_BIN"db/sample.sqlite3";
PATH_TARGET_DUMP=$PATH_BIN"dump/export_all.db";
PATH_TARGET_SCHEMA=$PATH_BIN"dump/export_schema.db";
PATH_TARGET_CSV=$PATH_BIN"dump/export_csv.csv";

##### DUMP ALL SCHEMA & DATA #####
sqlite3 $PATH_SOURCE .dump > $PATH_TARGET_DUMP;
echo "Done... Export all to: " $PATH_TARGET_DUMP;

#### DUMP SCHEMA (ONLY) #####
sqlite3 $PATH_SOURCE .schema > $PATH_TARGET_SCHEMA;
echo "Done... Export schema (only) to: " $PATH_TARGET_SCHEMA;

#### DUMP TO CSV FILE #####
QUERY="SELECT * FROM table";
# with header 
# sqlite3 -csv -header $PATH_SOURCE $QUERY > $PATH_TARGET_CSV;
# without header
sqlite3 -csv $PATH_SOURCE $QUERY > $PATH_TARGET_CSV;
echo "Done... Export csv file to: " $PATH_TARGET_CSV;

echo "All Done !";
```

You can also fork in my gist file [here](https://gist.github.com/zeroc0d3/b74a35ce52a0f5225c906adce2cf09e5)

Answer (score 0):

The following python3 code snippet might be of assistance:

```
import os, fnmatch
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

#creates a directory without throwing an error
def create_dir(dir):
  if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
    print("Created Directory : ", dir)
  else:
    print("Directory already existed : ", dir)
  return dir

#finds files in a directory corresponding to a regex query
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result



#convert sqlite databases(.db,.sqlite) to pandas dataframe(excel with each table as a different sheet or individual csv sheets)
def save_db(dbpath=None,excel_path=None,csv_path=None,extension="*.sqlite",csvs=True,excels=True):
    if (excels==False and csvs==False):
      print("Atleast one of the parameters need to be true: csvs or excels")
      return -1

    #little code to find files by extension
    if dbpath==None:
      files=find(extension,os.getcwd())
      if len(files)>1:
        print("Multiple files found! Selecting the first one found!")
        print("To locate your file, set dbpath=<yourpath>")
      dbpath = find(extension,os.getcwd())[0] if dbpath==None else dbpath
      print("Reading database file from location :",dbpath)

    #path handling

    external_folder,base_name=os.path.split(os.path.abspath(dbpath))
    file_name=os.path.splitext(base_name)[0] #firstname without .
    exten=os.path.splitext(base_name)[-1]   #.file_extension

    internal_folder="Saved_Dataframes_"+file_name
    main_path=os.path.join(external_folder,internal_folder)
    create_dir(main_path)


    excel_path=os.path.join(main_path,"Excel_Multiple_Sheets.xlsx") if excel_path==None else excel_path
    csv_path=main_path if csv_path==None else csv_path

    db = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
    tables = cursor.fetchall()
    print(len(tables),"Tables found :")

    if excels==True:
      #for writing to excel(xlsx) we will be needing this!
      try:
        import XlsxWriter
      except ModuleNotFoundError:
        !pip install XlsxWriter

    if (excels==True and csvs==True):
      writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
      i=0
      for table_name in tables:
          table_name = table_name[0]
          table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, db)
          i+=1
          print("Parsing Excel Sheet ",i," : ",table_name)
          table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=table_name, index=False)
          print("Parsing CSV File ",i," : ",table_name)
          table.to_csv(os.path.join(csv_path,table_name + '.csv'), index_label='index')

      writer.save()


    elif excels==True:
      writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
      i=0
      for table_name in tables:
          table_name = table_name[0]
          table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, db)
          i+=1
          print("Parsing Excel Sheet ",i," : ",table_name)
          table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=table_name, index=False)

      writer.save()

    elif csvs==True:
      i=0
      for table_name in tables:
          table_name = table_name[0]
          table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, db)
          i+=1
          print("Parsing CSV File ",i," : ",table_name)
          table.to_csv(os.path.join(csv_path,table_name + '.csv'), index_label='index')
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return 0
save_db();
```